# Bouancy with Newtons second law

Tags: fluid-mechanics

To calculate the height of the submerged fraction of an object, the equilibrium sum of the forces is used: $F_g - F_B = 0$.

But if the height of the submerged fraction is to be calculated dynamically, Newton's Second Law is used:

$\frac{d^2h}{dt^2}=F_g-F_B $.

However, this will cause some heavy oscillations as no resistive forces are included.

If I want to get rid of the oscillations I must include some damping, and the only Resistive Force must be drag force, but the drag force will be higher when the object is moving downwards as the fluid pushes the bottom area right?

So my actual question is how can I implement damping to the system is there a way to only consider viscous damping?

Comment: What does "hugger" mean, in the second last paragraph: " ... drag force will be hugger ..."? Is it supposed be "higher"?

Comment: oh sorry, yes it is higher

Answer (score 1):

There are several sources of damping: Water surface tension and water viscous losses and the shape and surface adhesion of the buoy.

You would start by imparting the water surface tension, $ 0.07275 \ J/m^2Nm \ $, Then add drag and viscus effects of the displaced water, which is complicated and is usually left to empirical values driven from tests and compliled using advanced numerical analysis methods.

If you drop a pebble into the water after starting the initial wave it will dissipate the energy of impact and level off. The same thing causes damping on a vibrating buoy.

There are many studies on this subject and practical use in creating energy by extracting electricity from the undulations of buoys.

here is a good research article on Researchgate (318 pages). I think the membership is free for most of the articles. [reaserchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275645326_The_NumWEC_project_Numerical_estimation_of_energy_delivery_from_a_selection_of_wave_energy_converters_-_final_report)

'

[image: damping]

'

[image: buoy]

Answer (score 0):

Viscous damping is produced purely by shear forces arising in Couette flow. The dampers involve motion of a bunch of parallel plates into another bunch of parallel plates inside a fluid chamber. The gap between plates on either set is slightly larger than the thickness of the plates, so as any plate slides between two plates on the other set, shear stresses produced by this motion tries to dampen it. Apparently, such dampers cannot produce significant damping for practical applications.

Example

A steel spring has no viscous damping. Resilient elements of rubber do have an internal damping, maybe comparable to viscous damping.

experimentally determining the viscous damping coefficient of a spring?
Experiment?
The amplitude of vibration decreases with a factor exp(-t/Tau). [t is time, tau is time-constant, a measure for damping]. Monitor the vibration for at least 10 periods of the eigen vibration. From this registration you can determine tau.